# Use file system watcher to monitor files being copied?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, access-control

i am doing an application that uses file system watcher and the main aim is to monitor files that are being copied , so i looked at the file system watcher method i found 4 events i can sue , they are change , delete , rename and create , i didn't find the copy event , umm and i'd like to watch specific files and when a user tries to copy the files i prevent him from doing so using the file system watcher method , so in file system watcher is there any method for copying files monitoring that i can use ? , sorry my question may look stupid but this is the first time i use file system watcher and i read about it a lot and almost all people agree about the 4 events that can be used in that class .

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do DRM.  Don't.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? there are similar functions in windows server

Comment: And if your software is not started, he can copy ? What are you trying to achieve ? because IMHO your solution is not the good one.

Comment: well , the main aim is to protect files on a usb flash drive it is for security reasons , ummm i try to make the files executable but can`t be copied . that`s what i want to achieve

Answer (score 6):

There is no operation called copying a file.
Rather, copying is a combination of reading one file and writing another one.

You cannot reliably do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with FileSystemWatcher

May be monitor Clipboard and if you find list of files, check location of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can at least have a notification of who copied the file by using WMI notification. Another option is restricting user access to the folders.

Try this link.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176985.aspx#EHAA

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check that the executable is launched from the usb key at the beginning of your software ? this way the user who copied the file won't be able to launch it even if he copied the exe.